In Apache config, do Redirects or Rewrite Rules take precedence?
I want a domain on Apache to exist purely as a redirect. To that end, I create /etc/apache2/sites-available/redirect.example.info.conf as follows:
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName redirect.example.info
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    Redirect / https://example.com/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

When I run certbot --apache, this is rewritten to:
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName redirect.example.info
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    Redirect / https://example.com/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =redirect.example.info
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

And a new file, /etc/apache2/sites-available/redirect.example.info-le-ssl.conf is created:
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName redirect.example.info
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    Redirect / https://example.com/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/ca-webs.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/ca-webs.com/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>

This does work as desired. The redirects run http://redirect.example.info → https://redirect.example.info → https://example.com. But it isn’t obvious to me how it’s working. The rewritten file has both a Redirect command and a RewriteRule command, and I’d have thought that the Redirect (coming first) would take precedence. How is this file actually evaluated?

AFAIK certbot --apache does not do a rigorous examination of the existing HTTP VirtualHost, it simply copies all existing directives and adds TLS directives to generate a new HTTPS VirtualHost.
The  plain HTTP VirtualHost is then modified to include a conditional HTTP --> HTTPS redirect (to only redirect URI's for which certbot  has configured a certificate).
The resulting config is suitable for most use-cases, but in your case the result is sub-optimal and I'd suggest that you manually edit the plain HTTP Virtual Host.  Remove the Rewrite* directives that certbot added and revert to your original config that sends visitors  directly  from http://redirect.example.info  to  https://example.com to prevent that redundant intermediate visit to https://redirect.example.info.

As to why the Rewrite* directives take precedence although they appear after the Redirect directive: that is because the effective apache httpd configuration is not solely the result of where, in which order and in which  container, configuration directives are placed and grouped, but also depends on which module(s) the directives belong to.
That info is not immediately obvious in the "merging" section of the manual https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/sections.html#merging

Relationship between modules and configuration sections
One question
that often arises after reading how configuration sections are merged
is related to how and when directives of specific modules like
mod_rewrite are processed. The answer is not trivial and needs a bit
of background. Each httpd module manages its own configuration, and
each of its directives in httpd.conf specify one piece of
configuration in a particular context. httpd does not execute a
command as it is read.
At runtime, the core of httpd iterates over the defined configuration
sections in the order described above to determine which ones apply to
the current request. When the first section matches, it is considered
the current configuration for this request. If a subsequent section
matches too, then each module with a directive in either of the
sections is given a chance to merge its configuration between the two
sections. The result is a third configuration, and the process goes on
until all the configuration sections are evaluated.
After the above step, the "real" processing of the HTTP request
begins: each module has a chance to run and perform whatever tasks
they like. They can retrieve their own final merged configuration from
the core of the httpd to determine how they should act.

For mod_rewrite the subtle detail is probably in the sentence "each module has a chance to run and perform whatever tasks they like".
Modules can/must register themselves via request processing hooks  to be able to ”do what they like” at the right moment and mod_rewrite uses that to come first (or at least early) with the APR_HOOK_FIRST hook https://github.com/apache/httpd/blob/c72b74ccef72fb56becd55888a3aa783c4ab5b6b/modules/mappers/mod_rewrite.c#L5702
As far as I know that is how Rewrite* directives gain precedence over others, regardless of how/where those other directives are ordered.
You can get insights of the hooks and all enabled modules and their ordering by enabling mod_info (don't forget to add ACL's to the server-info URL).
